# close formula for hypergeometric ${}_3 F_2$

Tags: real-analysis, closed-form, hypergeometric-function

I search a close form for the general hypergeometric ${}_3 F_2(1, 1, 1/2+A/2; 3/2, 2; 1 )$ where $A$ is exclusive a negative integer even.

It seems that the close form is ( rational number ) + $(2\ln 2)/(-A+1)$.

So i need help for the formula about the rational number.
Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

Wolfram Alpha gives the [answer](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=HypergeometricPFQ%5B%7B1%2C+1%2C+1%2F2+%2B+A%7D%2C+%7B3%2F2%2C+2%7D%2C+1%5D) which can simplify as
$$\, _3F_2\left(1,1,A+\frac{1}{2};\frac{3}{2},2;1\right)=\frac{\psi (1-A)+\gamma +2\log (2)}{1-2 A}=\frac{H_{-A}+2\log (2)}{1-2 A}$$

Comment: This is a proof outline. By Thomae's transformation one have $$\, _3F_2\left(t,1,a;\frac{3}{2},2;1\right)=\frac{\Gamma \left(\frac{3}{2}-a\right) \, _3F_2\left(t,\frac{1}{2},\frac{3}{2}-a;\frac{3}{2},\frac{5}{2}-a;1\right)}{\Gamma \left(\frac{5}{2}-a\right)}$$
Now apply partial fractions termwise in the latter series: $$\frac{1}{(n+1/2)(n+3/2-a)}\to \frac{C}{n+1/2}+\frac{D}{n+3/2-a}$$
So it becomes two $_2F_1$, which can be summed by Gauss theorem, yielding a Gamma form. Now let $t\to1$ and calculate the limit gives the polygamma form, completing the proof.

Comment: @User. This is very nice ! I never thought about changing the first argument. Thanks. :-)